# PHP pagination and IDs

Tags: php, pagination

please i need your help greatly. I am creating a page that will have all the lists of the registered members using pagination, but when i click on any user it takes me to only the 'profile.php?user=3' instead of the user's id profile if you understand what i mean, please show me what i did wrong in my coding:

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>MEMBERS</title>
<link rel="icon" href="guyt.gif" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<div id="sidebar">
<br>

<?php include 'lists.php'; ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the lists.php which contains the pagination:

```
    <?php
$per_page = 5;

if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = 1;
} else {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

if($page<=1)
$start = 0;
else
    $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;

    $mem_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM register");
    while($run_mem = mysql_fetch_array($mem_query)){
        $id = $run_mem['id'];
        $first = getuser($id, 'first');
        $last = getuser($id, 'last');
    }


$sql = "SELECT * FROM register";

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));

$num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $per_page);



$sql .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
While($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<div class='header'><table width='98%'><tr><td><div align='left'>" . $row['first'] . " " . $row['last'] . "</div></td><td><div align='right'><a href='profile.php?user=$id'>VISIT PROFILE</a></div></td></tr></table></div><br>";
    }

$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;

echo "<hr>";

if($prev > 0)
echo "<a href='?page=$prev' class='box'>Previous</a></font> ";

if($page < ceil($num_rows/$per_page))
echo " <a href='?page=$next' class='box'>Next</a></font>";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please look at your code critically,you are generating the id within the first loop and assigning the value in the second loop. That is your problem,because after the execution of first loop the variable id will be assigned to the last member id which is basically 3. It will also be nice to show the profile.php.

Solution
change your url to this
<a href='profile.php?user='.$row['id']>VISIT PROFILE</a>
```